# \lowercase trick vs. \gdef

Tags: macros, tex-core, best-practices

In this MWE I define an environment where a particular letter is active with some meaning once with the `\lowercase` trick and once with `\gdef`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\catcode`\A=\active
\gdefA#1{(#1)}
\endgroup
\newenvironment{foo}{\catcode`\A=\active }{}

\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\B
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{(#1)}
\newenvironment{baz}{\catcode`\B=\active }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}foo Abaz A{bar}\end{foo}

\begin{baz}foo Bbaz B{bar}\end{baz}

\end{document}
```

and both environments yield of course the same output:

[image]

I wonder if there is some reason to prefer one way instead of the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, the `\lowercase` trick doesn't require the assignment to be global, so whatever definition you change, it will be restricted to the current scope, which is usually what you want (if it's not, you can use `\gdef` in the `\lowercase` code too).

But probably the main advantage is that the `\lowercase` trick allows you to “generate” the active character on-the-fly, while with the `\gdef` approach the active character has to be typed directly (actually, in the `\lowercase` approach the active character *is* typed directly, but it's the `~`, which is already active).

Suppose your environment takes an argument, which is the character to be made active. With the naïve `\gdef` approach it's not possible:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{baz}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{%
  \endgroup\def~}##1{(##1)}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{baz}{B}foo Bbaz B{bar}\end{baz}

{\catcode`\B=\active \show B}

\end{document}
```

and `\show B` shows that the definition of “active-char-B” didn't change globally:

```
> B=undefined.
l.16 {\catcode`\B=\active \show B
                                 }
?
```

---

You can use yet another trick to avoid the `\gdef` in the first approach. If you do, assuming `\@firstofone` has its usual LaTeX meaning (`\@firstofone=\long macro:#1->#1`):

```latex
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\A=\active
  \@firstofone{%
\endgroup
\defA}#1{(#1)}
```

then the argument of `\@firstofone`, `\endgroup\defA` will be tokenized before the `\endgroup` is processed, so `\defA` will still be `\def` `<active-char-A>` even after the `\endgroup`, so the change will be limited to the current scope. However if you want to make an environment with that, you still can't automatically generate the active characters, so you need to “activate” each character one-by-one (and ensure that they are active at the time you define the environment).

---

Here's one example of how the `\lowercase` approach is better to locally change the meaning of a character while still preserving its meaning outside the scope of your macro/environment. In this example I use the fact that French `babel` makes `!` an active character. Consider this example using the `\lowercase` trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newenvironment{baz}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{%
  \endgroup\def~}##1{(##1)}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}{}
\begin{document}
\show! % > !=macro:->\active@prefix !\active@char!
\begin{baz}{!}foo !baz !{bar}\end{baz}
\show! % > !=macro:->\active@prefix !\active@char!
\end{document}
```

and this one using a directly typed `!`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newenvironment{baz}[1]{\catcode`!=\active}{}
\begin{document}
\show! % > !=macro:->\active@prefix !\active@char!
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\!=\active
  \@firstofone{%
\endgroup
\def!}#1{(#1)}
\makeatother
\begin{baz}{!}foo !baz !{bar}\end{baz}
\show! % > !=macro:#1->(#1)
\end{document}
```

They are much the same code. They key differences are:

1) In the `\lowercase` version the definition can go in the preamble, because it dynamically (abusing the meaning of the word) generates the active `!` character without the need of setting it up first. In the `\gdef` version (in which I didn't use `\gdef`, but just to keep the naming in your question) the setup of the `!` character to be used needs to go after `\begin{document}`, otherwise your definition is overridden by `babel`.

and 2) You lose `babel`'s definition of `!` because you have to globally define the meaning of the `active character !` (or whatever code which happens to have an active meaning and you use in your environment). The `\lowercase` version allows you to keep this definition local so you do not need to worry about that.

Overall, there is little reason to prefer the “`\gdef` approach” over the `\lowercase`. It's harder to set up, it's possibly problematic when interacting with other packages, and doesn't allow you to programatically change characters.

Comment: Great! I guess the bottom line is that for some macro/environment which has to be defined globally anyway they are equivalent, while `\lowercase` is necessary for local definitions.

Comment: @campa The fact that the macro/environment needs to be locally does not interfere on the fact that you usually don't want to change the active definition of a character globally (unless you do, of course :-). For example, if you do that you might clash with `babel`'s definitions. What remains local in the `\lowercase` approach is the definition of the active character. Note that the ´\show B` shows `undefined` instead of `B=macro:#1->(#1)`. I'll add another example with `babel`.

Comment: @campa I added another example

Comment: Excellent and great also for me!