# Using characters to delimit commands (like markdown)

Tags: macros, verbatim, characters

I recently came accross the `\DefineShortVerb` command of the `fancyvrb` package, which lets you "[define a special character as an abbreviation
to enclose verbatim text](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/doc/fancyvrb-doc.pdf)", so for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}
|this is verbatim|
\end{document}
```

I was wondering if and how this could be done for any other character and any other command. For example, say I wanted the text enclosed by the character `` ` `` to be displayed in italic:

```
\documentclass{article}
% some code
\begin{document}
`this` and \textit{this} should be the same.
\end{document}
```

how could I do this?

Comment: This kind of markup is good for text with little typographic needs. I'd avoid it: with a good editor it's easy to set up “command-i” (or “control-i”) to insert `\textit{}` and place the cursor between the braces.

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15374/4427 ?

Comment: I hadn't, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic idea of `\DefineShortVerb` is that it makes the character in the argument active (`` \catcode`#1=\active ``), so that the character behaves like a macro. Then it defines that character to be a verbatim command using the ["lowercase trick"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513607/134574). You can change that to define the character to a custom macro.

Here's a `\DefineShortCommand<char>{<definition>}` macro which defines the `<char>` to expand to `<definition>`. This eventually does something like `\def<char>#1<char>{<definition>}`, in which `<char>` is an active character token. In the `<definition>`, `#1` is the argument, grabbed between the first and the next (brace-balanced) `<char>`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\def\DefineShortCommand#1{%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~##1~}}
\begin{document}

\DefineShortCommand\`{\textit{#1}}
`this` and \textit{this} should be the same.

\end{document}
```

Take care not to activate "dangerous" characters and beware with possible conflicts with `babel`.

---

To use with `Verbatim`, the character `` ` `` is especially painful because this character is reset by LaTeX's `\@noligs` to avoid that it forms ligatures in verbatim mode. `fancyvrb` uses `\@noligs` after the user's catcode settings, so anything you change to the character `` ` `` is overridden. You need to remove it from the verbatim ligature list:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\def\DefineShortCommand#1{%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~##1~}}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'\do\-}
\def\backtickit{\DefineShortCommand\`{\textit{##1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{Verbatim}[codes={\backtickit}]
  x=1/sqrt(z**2) <- This is an `equation`
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

---

As Mico noted, when two `` ` `` are used (like in ``` ``should'' ```) you usually don't want to apply the special formatting. To detect this case you can check that the argument of active-`` ` `` is empty and then use the original `` ` `` character instead.

Suppose you have a `\tlifempty{<token list>}{<empty>}{<not empty>}` (shown below) conditional, then this could be accomplished with:

```latex
\DefineShortCommand\`{%
  \tlifempty{#1}
    {\char96\char96\relax}
    {\textit{#1}}}
```

(96 is the ASCII code for `` ` ``).

To go an extra mile and allow the eventual usage of `` ` `` (or other character that you happen to use with `\DefineShortCommand`) in an expansion-only context, you need to save the original meaning of `` ` `` and then retrieve it later with an auxiliary macro.

In the code below, `\DefineShortCommand` saves the original meaning of the argument as (for example `` ` ``) `\the@char@96`. Later you can retrieve it with `` \thechar{`} ``. As an extra safety, the code does some normalisation so that both `` ` `` or `` \` `` retrieve the same character:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\DefineShortCommand#1{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname the@char@\number`#1\endcsname
    {\unless\if\@backslashchar\string#1%
       \string#1\else\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\fi}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~##1~}}
\def\thechar#1{\csname the@char@\number`#1\endcsname}
% Checking if the argument is empty
\def\tlifempty#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DefineShortCommand\`{%
  \tlifempty{#1}
    {\thechar{`}\thechar{\`}}
    {\textit{#1}}}

`this` and \textit{this} ``should'' be the same.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried using it in a `Verbatim` environment, with the option `[commandchars=\\`]`, but that just printed the ` character. Is it possible to get that to work?

Comment: @noibe The `commandchar` key takes three tokens as argument, not just one. These tokens are supposed to be replacements to ``\``, `{`, and `}`, respectively. You could use, for instance, `commandchars=|[]`. But this wouldn't help you here. The appropriate key is `codes` (plus a few tweaks :-). See the edit

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote twice if I could.

Comment: How might your first solution be generalized to allow the continued use of "normal" (i.e., consecutive) double backticks, as in ``that''?

Comment: @Mico With a bit more code, checking if the argument of the active-`\`` is empty. For the specific case of the backtick one could use some kind of lookahead with futurelet, but this would be more fragile (not that making `\`` active is robust ;-), so I opted to generalise for any character and leave the emptyness check in the definition of `\``. See the edit :-)

Answer (score 6):

> I want the text enclosed by [backtick] characters to be displayed in italic

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It doesn't require making the backtick character, `` ` ``, "active".

[image]

Observe that the "normal" use of *double* backticks, ``` `` ```, as in ``` ``that'' ```, is not affected by the processing of material enclosed in pairs of single backticks.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}  
%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function backtick2textit ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "``(.-)''" , "@@@@@%1@@@@@" ) -- save ``...'' cases
   s = s:gsub ( "`(..-)`", "\\textit{%1}" )   -- ignore consecutive backticks
   s = s:gsub ( "@@@@@(.-)@@@@@" , "``%1''" ) -- restore ``...'' cases
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}    
%% LaTeX-side code:
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", backtick2textit , 
   "backtick2textit" )}}

\begin{document}
\dots\ and `this` and ``that'' and ``why'' and `who` and \dots
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to explain how the solution works:

- The Lua function `backtick2textit` is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at a very early stage, i.e., before TeX performs its usual work of expanding macros, etc.
- The function `backtick2textit` employs the Lua function `string.gsub` (I believe that "gsub" stands for "global substitution") to perform its job.

  - First, strings enclosed in double-backticks/double apostrophes (non-greedy matching) are set aside.
  - A pattern match occurs if a backtick is encountered, followed by 1 or more arbitrary characters (non-greedy matching), followed by another backtick. If a match occurs, the material enclosed by the backticks is encased in a `\textit` directive.
  - Finally, the material to rendered in double-quote marks is restored.
- The Lua function will not perform correctly if you use both single and double quote characters to quote material. The code posted above doesn't guard against this eventuality as I assume that you mentioned the use of backtick characters just as an example.