# What does the comment-pln code actually do?

Tags: macros, plain-tex, comments, sourcecode, catcodes

The `comment-pln` code on CTAN ([link](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment-pln)) defines the plain TeX macros `\begincomment` and `\endcomment`, that ignore everything typed in between. The entire code base is included below:

```
%       Comment.tex
% Macro to allow block comments in TeX
%
% Usage: Text between \begincomment and \endcomment is ignored; i.e.
%
% text
% \begincomment
%    this text is ignored
% \endcomment
% more text
%
% Notes: Do NOT nest.
%        The \endcomment MUST appear at the end of a line.
%        TeX processes each line of ignored text, so the macro
%           is not particularly fast.  Use sparingly.  The main use
%           is to cause TeX to pass over small blocks of text.
%
% J.C. Alexander,  May, 1986
%
\edef\Saveatcatcode{\the\catcode`\@}
\catcode`\@=11
\def\newcodes@{\edef\S@veslashcatcode{\the\catcode`\\}
               \edef\S@velbraccatcode{\the\catcode`\{}
               \edef\S@verbraccatcode{\the\catcode`\}}
               \edef\S@venumsgcatcode{\the\catcode`\#}
               \edef\S@veperctcatcode{\the\catcode`\%}
 \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12 \catcode`\#=12
 \catcode`\%=12\relax}
\def\oldcodes@{\catcode`\\=\S@veslashcatcode
               \catcode`\{=\S@velbraccatcode
               \catcode`\}=\S@verbraccatcode
               \catcode`\#=\S@venumsgcatcode
               \catcode`\%=\S@veperctcatcode
               \relax}
\def\begincomment{\newcodes@\endlinechar=10 \comment@}
{\lccode`\!=`\\
\lowercase{\gdef\comment@#1^^J{\comment@@#1!endcomment\comment@@@}%
\gdef\comment@@#1!endcomment{\futurelet\next\comment@@@}%
\gdef\comment@@@#1\comment@@@{\ifx\next\comment@@@\let
\next=\comment@\else\def\next{\oldcodes@\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax}%
 \fi\next}}}
\catcode`\@=\Saveatcatcode
```

> What is this black magic?

The first few lines I get: It gives a way to redefine the catcodes for `\`, `{`, `}`, `#`, and `%` to be "other" and reverting the change. Presumably this will cause them not do their usual voodoo when the comment is treated as comment.

(**However**: those are the 0, 1, 2, 6, and 14 characters; why is it `$`, `_`, and `^` can be omitted? )

I also think I sort of get the definition of `\begincomment`: It changes the catcodes, sets the endline character, and "calls the macro" `\comment@` (which I assume due to the change of endline character actually eats up the commented portion as part of its processing).

> My main questions are therefore: how exactly does this `\comment@` work and how does it relate to the code in the group immediately after that? I have zero idea what those three `\gdef`s are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before trying to understand that definition, let us give it a proper indentation and line numbers so it (arguably) is more readable:

```
01:{%
02:  \lccode`\!=`\\
03:  \lowercase{%
04:    \gdef\comment@#1^^J{\comment@@#1!endcomment\comment@@@}%
05:    \gdef\comment@@#1!endcomment{\futurelet\next\comment@@@}%
06:    \gdef\comment@@@#1\comment@@@{%
07:      \ifx\next\comment@@@
08:        \let\next=\comment@
09:      \else
10:        \def\next{\oldcodes@\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax}%
11:      \fi
12:      \next}%
13:  }%
14:}
```

It starts by opening a group (line 1) to make the following `\lccode` setting local. Then it changes the `\lccode` of `!` to that of `\`, and then issues `\lowercase` on the remaining block of code. This is the so-called [`\lowercase` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513607/134574) for injecting a character with an unusual catcode in a definition. The contraption:

```
{\lccode`\!=`\\
 \lowercase{<code>}%
}
```

could be replaced by

```
\begingroup
  \lccode`\!=`\\
  \lowercase{%
\endgroup
<code>}
```

then the `\gdef` could be replaced by `\def`. But back at the definition. After `\lowercase` has done its thing, all tokens who have a non-zero `\lccode` were replaced by their lowercase counterparts, and this includes the replacement of the character `!` by *the character* `\` (that is, a catcode 12 backslash). I'll show them as `\\` in the block of code above to differentiate form the catcode 0 backslashes, but they are actually single `\`<sub>12</sub> tokens:

```
04:    \gdef\comment@#1^^J{\comment@@#1\\endcomment\comment@@@}%
05:    \gdef\comment@@#1\\endcomment{\futurelet\next\comment@@@}%
06:    \gdef\comment@@@#1\comment@@@{%
07:      \ifx\next\comment@@@
08:        \let\next=\comment@
09:      \else
10:        \def\next{\oldcodes@\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax}%
11:      \fi
12:      \next}%
```

Now here's what each of these three commands do: `\comment@` grabs everything until the next `^^J` (which, since the `\endlinechar` was set to 10, is the line end) and does `\comment@@#1\\endcomment\comment@@@` (remember that `\\` is a single backslash). 
There are two possibilities here: the first is if `#1` is a "normal" line of code to be commented, and the second is if `#1` is the string `\\endcomment`.

Now let's see each possibility separately: if the line doesn't contain `\\endcomment`, then `\comment@@` will grab everything up to the `\\endcomment` left by `\comment@`, discard it, and do `\futurelet\next\comment@@@`. Since everything to the `\\endcomment` was discarded, the next token is *another* `\comment@@@`. Now the `\futurelet` does its thing and (the first) `\comment@@@` is expanded, and checks if the `\next` token is also `\comment@@@`. If so, it does `\let\next=\comment@` and another line is processed.

When a line that contains `\\endcomment` is found, `\comment@@` will use that as delimiter, and the `\futurelet\next\comment@@@` thing will assign *something else* to  `\next`, other than `\comment@@@`. In this case, the `\ifx` test in `\comment@@@` will return false and `\next` will be redefined to return the catcodes to normal with `\oldcodes@`, and the processing is done.

Comment: Okay, so just to make sure I understand: because of the change of catcodes to be enforced by `\begincomment`, it needs a way to detect `\endcommend` with `\` having catcode 12; that's why the `\lowercase` trick is needed, it allows us to still use `\` with catcode 0 but introduce a new character (using lowercasing on `!` that has the same character code but catcode 12). So that part is clear. The case where the line doesn't contain `\\endcomment` is also clear.

Comment: For the final paragraph, the reason is that because `\comment@` stashes another `\\endcomment`, so `\comment@@` is essentially asked to process `\\endcomment\\endcomment`, the first copy is treated as the delimiter, so then `\futurelet\next\comment@@@` will now be followed by `\\endcomment\comment@@@` and so `\next` is now something that is _not_ `\comment@@@` and that breaks the loop. Wow.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, that's exactly it! This is the type of line-by-line verbatim processor. It's similar to LaTeX's `filecontents` environment, and to the one from `fancyvrb`, if I'm not mistaken. There's also the type that grabs the entire environment in one go, like the `macrocode` environment from the `doc` package, and token-by-token type, `listings` (I'm sure there are others, but these are the most common ones).

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `\newcodes@` saves the current category codes of `\ { } # %` into macros and changes them to 12.

Making the backslash into an “other character” is necessary not in order to block interpretation of macros, which would be discarded before expansion is attempted, but in order to avoid TeX seeing *conditionals* and keep their nesting in skipped branches. Also appearances of `\comment@@@` in the commented block would ruin everything.

Braces are made catcode 12 so TeX will not try and keep their nesting into account. Without this, a `{` in a line and `}` in another line might be disastrous. The percent is made other so that it doesn't mask the end-of-line.

I see no apparent reason for changing the catcode of `#`; however this avoids its “doubling” when absorbed in the argument of a macro.

The other special characters are not a problem, because all found tokens will be discarded. They'd need treatment if we wanted to do verbatim printing.

The macro `\oldcodes@` restores the category codes that have changed.

Now the most important macros.

First `\begincomment` executes `\newcodes@` and sets the end-of-line mechanism to deliver character number 10, in double-hat notation `^^J`. Then `\comment@` is executed.

What's its job? It looks forward for `^^J` (that is up to the end of the line), making the argument to be whatever is found in between; then it delivers `\comment@@` followed by the argument followed by the *characters* `\endcomment`, the first category code 12, the other 11, ending with `\comment@@@`.

The `\lowercase` is used so every `!` in its argument is changed into a backslash before doing anything else; since no uppercase character appears, that's the only change. Remember that `\lowercase` only affects *characters* and leaves control sequences alone.

Thus the macro `\comment@@` is defined to have an argument delimited by `\endcomment` (not a macro). Its main purpose is to discard the argument, but it also does `\futurelet\next\comment@@@`.

Let's see an example that will help discussing the other macros:

```
\begincomment
foo
\endcomment
```

After doing the assignments of category codes and to `\endlinechar`, `\comment@` is found. The end-of-line hasn't yet be tokenized, but it will be now, when `\comment@` looks for its argument. In this case it's empty, so

```
\comment@@!endcomment\comment@@@
```

is placed in the input stream (I denote by `!endcomment` the eleven characters described above). The (empty) argument is discarded and the input stream will have

```
\futurelet\next\comment@@@\comment@@@
```

Then `\next` is set equal to `\comment@@@` and `\comment@@@` is expanded. Its definition is to collect as an argument whatever comes along up to the first `\comment@@@` token. In this case, nothing. It then examines the meaning of `\next`.

In this case `\next` is the same as `\comment@@@`, so `\next` is set equal to `\comment@` and the false branch is skipped over. Then `\next`, that is `\comment@` is executed, which will see

```
foo^^J
```

and do essentially the same (try following it). After this,

```
\comment@!endcomment^^J
```

remains on the input stream. This is transformed into

```
\comment@@!endcomment!endcomment\comment@@@
```

and the argument to `\comment@@` is empty (it wouldn't be if some character preceded `\endcomment` on the same line. The *first* `!endcomment` is removed as part of processing the delimited argument and

```
\futurelet\next\comment@@@!endcomment\comment@@@
```

remains. Now `\next` is set to `!` (actually a catcode 12 backslash, of course) and the argument to `\comment@@@` is absorbed and discarded. Since `\next` is *not* `\comment@@@`, the endgame `` \oldcodes@\endlinechar`\^^M `` is executed.

**Important points.**

When a macro is defined, the tokens in its parameter text and replacement text are already in internal format and don't depend in any way on subsequent changes of category codes.

When a macro with delimited arguments is expanded, the delimiters are removed from the input stream along with the arguments and the removed tokens will be replaced by the macro's replacement text.

To the contrary, `\futurelet` never removes tokens.

When `\lowercase` changes a character, it doesn't change the category code. So with

```
{\lccode`!=`\\ \lowercase{!}}
```

one gets a category code 12 backslash. Note that the `\lccode` of `!` will revert to its previous value (usually 0) upon the end of the group. An equivalent way to do the same is

```
\begingroup\lccode`!=`\\ \lowercase{\endgroup!}
```

because `\lowercase` does not interpret any token it finds; so `\endgroup` will be executed *after* `!` has been changed to a backslash.

I'd probably write

```
\begingroup\lccode`\!=`\\ \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\comment@#1^^J{\comment@@#1!endcomment\comment@@@}%
  \def\comment@@#1!endcomment{\futurelet\next\comment@@@}%
}% end of \lowercase
\def\comment@@@#1\comment@@@{%
  \ifx\next\comment@@@
    \let\next=\comment@
  \else
    \def\next{\oldcodes@\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax}%
  \fi
  \next
}
```

Less braces to keep account of.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the catcode stuff, I see I was mistaken in my original assumptions.